# Uncaught ReferenceError: mktoPreFillFields is not defined

Tags: jquery, marketo

i am using mktoPreFillFields but it is throwing error that ( Uncaught ReferenceError: mktoPreFillFields is not defined )

```
MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form) {     
    var valSelect = mktoPreFillFields.nPSResponse;     
        if(valSelect <= 0) { 
        $(".trans").css("transform", "rotate(-45deg)" );
    }
});
```

Earlier it was working fine with same code without any error. But i don't know why its giving me error now. Any one have solution, Please share ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's hard to know what exactly is going on in this case without seeing the code in a larger context. That said, [mktoPreFillFields is not part of Marketo's Forms2 API](https://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/api-reference/)—I'm guessing this is interacting with some sort of WordPress plugin? By default, you cannot retrieve prefill fields with the forms API.